# check if the given date(in string format) has past present date using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date range like 12/20/12-12/24/12(start date-end date) in string format .
I need to check if start date has past the present date. Can it be done using JS or j-query?
the date range is in string ?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in JavaScript. Have you tried anything? Done any research?

Comment: No, you cannot use jQuery for date stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5619588/1643087 ...  this article gives a way to convert string intoo date but the format am not sure of ... i need it to be converted into MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: javascript has a load of (admittedly not very good) built in Date (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) functions and plenty of string functions to aid in splitting them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the power of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object!

```
var myString = "12/20/2012-12/24/2012",
    parts = myString.split("-");
if (Date.parse(parts[0]) < Date.now()) {
    alert("start date has past the present date");
}
```

You could as well write `new Date(parts[0]) < new Date`.

Answer (score 1):

using [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

```
var today = Date.today();
var yourDay = Date.parse(yourDateTimeString);
var result = Date.compare(today, yourDay);
var isValid= result == -1;
```

`compare` returns -1 if `today` is less than `yourDay`

Answer (score 0):

thanx evry1 .. i got the answer 
here it is ...

```
 function cancel()
{
        var eventId=status_ID.substr(0,status_ID.indexOf("-"));
        var status=status_ID.substr(status_ID.indexOf("-")+1,status_ID.indexOf(":")-4);
        var eventRange=status_ID.substr(status_ID.indexOf(":")+1,status_ID.length);


        //alert(status);
        //alert(eventRange);
        if(status=="OPEN"){

            var startDate = eventRange.substr(0,eventRange.indexOf("-"));

           //alert(startDate);
          // alert("open");
           var todayDay = new Date().getDate();
          // alert(todayDay);
           var todayMonth = new Date().getMonth();
           alert(todayMonth);
           var todayFullYear = new Date().getFullYear();

           var todayYear=todayFullYear.toString().substr(2,4);
          // alert(todayYear);

            parts = startDate.split("/");
           //alert(parts[0]);
           //alert(parts[1]);
           //alert(parts[2]);
           var flag1=false;
           if(parts[2]>todayYear){
               flag1=true;
           }
           if(parts[2]==todayYear){
               if(parts[1]>todayMonth+1)
               {
                   flag1=true;
               }
               if(parts[1]==todayMonth+1)
               {
                   if(parts[0]>todayDay)
                   {
                       flag1=true;
                   }
               }

           }
           if(flag1)
           {
               alert("event can be cancelled");

                document.forms[0].submit();
           }



           else
           {
               alert("event has already started");
               return false;
           }


          }
        else
        {
            alert("The event has closed");
        }

    }
```